# SqlAlchemy Mapper not returning clean UUIDs

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table which is being mapped with SqlAlchemy.  In that table is a UUID column.  When I try to query that table, I get the uuid in bytes_le format.  Is there some way I can tell the mapper to return a clean string representation instead?  Code for the mapper is:

```
Practice = Table('Practice',metadata,
                 schema='pulse',autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, quote_schema=True)
class PracticeMap(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.Name
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Name: %s, UUID: %s" % (self.Name, self.uuid)
mapper(PracticeMap,Practice)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can always reformat the uuid using the python uuid library:

```
import uuid
uuid_string = str(uuid.UUID(bytes_le=self.uuid))
```

If you only need the string representation for __repr__ that should do the trick.  If you want the uuid property of your object to live in string-land, you'll want to rename the column property and provide your own uuid property to wrap it.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, as I am passing a SqlAlchemy Query object to another function (using the SqlAlch field extensions for WTForms).